# The shell script does not execute the removing the files

Tags: bash, shell

I have the below script for removing the web cache and files from /tmp and /var/tmp directory to bring down the disk utilization percentage. When I execute the script it doesn't remove the files and gives nothing.

```
    #!/bin/bash

#set -x
#THRESHOLD=30
TEMP1=$(cd /tmp)
TEMP2=$(cd /var/tmp)
df -h | grep -v '^Filesystem' | awk '{print $1,$5}' | while read output;
do
  used=$(echo $output | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d '%' -f1)
  diskpart=$(echo $output | awk '{print $2}')
  if [[ "$used" -ge "30" ]]; then
    echo "Disk utilization percentage is more"
#    sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
    rm -rf "$TEMP1/*"
    rm -rf "$TEMP2/*"
  fi
done
```

Output below:

```
srikant@ubuntu:~$ ./example.sh 
srikant@ubuntu:~$ ./example.sh 
srikant@ubuntu:~$
```

The df -h command output:

```
srikant@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           393M   12M  382M   3% /run
/dev/sda1        19G  9.5G  8.2G  54% /
tmpfs           2.0G  272K  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           393M     0  393M   0% /run/user/121
tmpfs           393M   52K  393M   1% /run/user/1000
```

I tried with sudo before rm -rf and while executing the script also. But still it is not working.
Please help.

Comment: Line 4 is just `THRESHOLD=80` and should not be giving `line 4: /tmp/config-err-QLxjzY: Permission denied`. Can you please copy-paste the script from this post into a new file, rerun it, and post the result with the correct output and line numbers?

Comment: I ran with the below script.The script doesn't give any result though for one file I can see it is 54%:#!/bin/bash

#set -x
#THRESHOLD=30
TEMP1=$(cd /tmp)
TEMP2=$(cd /var/tmp)
df -h | grep -v '^Filesystem' | awk '{print $1,$5}' | while read output;
do
  used=$(echo $output | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d '%' -f1)
  diskpart=$(echo $output | awk '{print $2}')
  if [[ "$used" -ge "30" ]]; then
    echo "Disk utilization percentage is more"
    sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
    rm -rf "$TEMP1/*"
    rm -rf "$TEMP2/*"
  fi
done

Comment: Please edit the post instead of commenting

Comment: And then please delete unhelpful code in comments once you have updated your Q ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: Also, I think the error would have been obvious if you had uncomment `set -x`. Good luck.

Comment: It's a good thing that you had the `"$TEMP1/*"` quoted glob bug, because otherwise the `TEMP1=$(cd /tmp)` bug would have caused it to run `rm -rf /*` and delete everything on the system. [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) recommends `rm -rf "${TEMP2:?}"/*` to avoid accidentally doing this.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

When you generate `output` it only has two fields in it, the *original* `$1` and `$5` in the first  `awk '{print $1,$5}'`, for example `/dev/sda1` and `54%`.  Then in:

```
used=$(echo $output | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d '%' -f1)
```

you only have these two fields, so the `awk '{print $5}'` part gives an empty string.  It should be:

```
used=$(echo $output | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d '%' -f1)
```

In addition to that:

```
TEMP1=$(cd /tmp)
TEMP2=$(cd /var/tmp)
```

will be empty strings, because `cd` does not write anything to standard output.  This should be:

```
TEMP1='/tmp'
TEMP2='/var/tmp'
```

The quotes are optional in this case.

Also:

```
 rm -rf "$TEMP1/*"
```

will look for a literal file called `*`, since filename expansion is not done inside quotes!

EDIT:  My preferred solution would be to loose the external programs `awk` and `cut`:

```
temp1='/tmp'          # Avoid uppercase variable names
temp2='/var/tmp'      # they can collide with shell names

while read -r diskpart Size Used Avail Use Mounted
do
    # Remove the trailing %
    used=${Use%%%*}

    # A neater from of numeric comparison
    if (( used >= 30 ))  
    then
        echo "Disk utilization percentage is more"
        #sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

        # Note that putting * inside quotes won't be expanded
        rm -rf "$temp1"/*
        rm -rf "$temp2"/*
    fi
done < <(df -h)
```

Comment: Thank you. What files should I delete to bring down my disk utilization? after deleting tmp files the output is the same.

Comment: I could not possibly answer that without intimate knowledge of your system.  You would be better asking that question on a system administrator's forum rather than this, which is for programming questions.